# Do I need these js files?

Tags: community

I'm new to salesforce and trying to move a site out of salesforce to a different platform altogether. 
I've noticed there are some js files that are used when I look at the site in a browser but can't figure were there they are in salesforce. I think that they are generated by salesforce automatically. Can anyone tell me what these files do and if i need them in the new platform.

These are file names:

1. stub.js
2. 3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript
3. SfdcCore.js
4. picklist.js
5. VFState.js
6. PotentialFinder__AccessRecord_JS
7. PotentialFinder__PF_BasicCSS.css

Answer (score 0):

Nope if you are looking at these files in Static resource then they are not generated by Salesforce
Some options -
1. Users manually created these
2. It came as part of an installed package (can check installed package namespace for same)

Thanks,
Ray